# chaining multiple async dispatch in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to chain multiple actions together in the following fashion:

A. post user data to database

B. use posted data to query Elasticsearch for results

(I do A and B in parallel)

B1. with results from ES, query original database for results from two tables
B2. navigate to new page and update UI

I am using thunks right now to reason about my code, but I also found this async pattern to be extremely verbose:

```
export function fetchRecipes(request) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestRecipes(request))    
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveRecipes(request, json))
    )
  }
}
```

this, along with "requestRecipes" and "receiveRecipes" as other action creators seems like quite a bit just to make one async call. (a request, a receive, and a fetch function)

summary: when you're chaining 2-3 async actions whose outputs depend on each other (I need to promisify when possible), is there a more efficient means of doing so without writing 3 functions for each async call?

I figure there had to be a way. I'm pattern matching off of the Redux docs and soon became very overwhelmed with the functions I was creating

thanks a lot for the feedback!

Comment: I use this pattern; it's a lot of functions, but you can also create a factory that will create all those functions for you once when your app starts.  For example, see [this middleware](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/redux/middleware/clientMiddleware.js) in the react-redux-universal-hot-example (I find lots of inspiration from various patterns in that example repo).  At the same time, I don't claim it as the one true way of using redux in the context of async actions; I'd be curious to see other responses here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `redux-saga` instead of `redux-thunk` to achieve this more easily. `redux-saga` lets you describe your work using generators and is easier to reason about.

The first step is to describe how you pass your data to redux without worrying about services or async stuff.

**Actions**

```js
// actions.js
function createRequestTypes(base) {
  return {
    REQUEST: base + "_REQUEST",
    SUCCESS: base + "_SUCCESS",
    FAILURE: base + "_FAILURE",
  }
}

// Create lifecycle types on `RECIPES`
export const RECIPES = createRequestTypes("RECIPES")

// Create related actions
export const recipes = {
  // Notify the intent to fetch recipes
  request: request => ({type: RECIPES.REQUEST, request})
  // Send the response
  success: response => ({type: RECIPES.SUCCESS, response})
  // Send the error
  error: error => ({type: RECIPES.FAILURE, error})
}
```

**Reducer**

```js
// reducer.js
import * as actions from "./actions"

// This reducer handles all recipes
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.RECIPES.SUCCESS:
      // Replace current state
      return [...action.response]

    case actions.RECIPES.FAILURE:
      // Clear state on error
      return []

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**Services**

We also need the recipes API. When using `redux-saga` the simplest way to declare a service is to creating a (pure) function which reads the request as argument and returns a `Promise`.

```js
// api.js
const url = "https://YOUR_ENPOINT";

export function fetchRecipes(request) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
}
```

Now we need to wire actions and services. This is where `redux-saga` come in play.

```js
// saga.js
import {call, fork, put, take} from "redux-saga/effects"
import * as actions from "./actions"
import * as api from "./api"

function* watchFetchRecipes() {
  while (true) {
    // Wait for `RECIPES.REQUEST` actions and extract the `request` payload
    const {request} = yield take(actions.RECIPES.REQUEST)

    try {
      // Fetch the recipes
      const recipes = yield call(api.fetchRecipes(request))

      // Send a new action to notify the UI
      yield put(actions.fetchRecipes.success(recipes))
    } catch (e) {
      // Notify the UI that something went wrong
      yield put(actions.fetchRecipes.error(e))
    }
  }
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    fork(watchFetchRecipes)
  ]
}
```

And that's it! Whenever a component will send a `RECIPES.REQUEST` action, the saga will hook up and handle the async workflow.

```js
dispatch(recipes.request(req))
```

What's awesome with `redux-saga` is that you can easily chain async effects and dispatch actions during the workflow.

Comment: I'm commenting here because I needed to consult this again and your explanation is flipping awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the only time you actually update your UI is right at the end of all these asynchronous operations (B1).

If you don't use the results from the preceding async calls to change your application state / update your UI, what is the benefit of having these fine-grained actions?

Of course there are things like "loading / request started" and "finished loading / request stopped", but it seems to me, that in your case, you could just do the chained async calls outside of redux (in some kind of API-layer) and only use one action.
This action dispatches a "REQUEST_STARTED", then calls the API-layer, which does the DB-calls and elasticsearch request etc., and then dispatches either "REQUEST_SUCCESS" or "REQUEST_FAILURE", based on the result of the promise, which will give you the data you need to update your UI.

This way, the state in redux only concerns itself with ONE side-effect, instead of the implementation details of your chained calls. Also, your action gets a lot simpler, because it just handles the results of one async call.